# Looking for a .NET 4 ThreadPool

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, threadpool

I am looking for a good ThreadPool implementation. I understand that the .NET ThreadPool has been rewritten/improved in .NET 4, but I doubt that it suits my needs.

I have a varying number of tasks that have to be executed in parallel. I want to be able to control the maximum number of threads that work on these tasks, and if possible be able to priorize the tasks. Idle threads should be disposed and new threads should be created when necessary, up to the specified minimum/maximum.

As I understand it, I can't control the number of threads the .NET ThreadPool uses **to process *my* tasks** (don't want to affect the rest of the application, i.e. delegates) and I can't assign a number of threads to only work on my tasks.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to use the .NET ThreadPool in my scenario?
- If not, which good (preferably free) ThreadPool implementations are out there that I should look at? (.NET Framework 4 and Windows Azure compatible)

EDIT:
Added varying number of threads as a requirement.

Comment: All of your other questions have answers, you should accept some soon otherwise people are less likely to answer this question

Comment: You are right, I revisited some older questions and accepted answers there (though they weren't precisely what I was looking for, but if that's how the system works, so be it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at that library.

http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks good but seems to not be developed actively any longer?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the System.Threading.Tasks.Task class. Simplified, it's like using the ThreadPool but it gives you back Tasks, which have a similar API to Threads. Don't think you can prioritise Tasks though, but you did say you want to run stuff in parallel.

Comment: You can write a custom TaskScheduler, which could give you prioritization. See e.g. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/parallelextensions/thread/93100c88-c19f-42d7-9975-cd5415989a1a

Comment: TaskScheduler goes in the direction of what I'm looking for, thanks Joe. Perhaps there is already a Scheduler implementation that does what I'm looking for, I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Beauty of the implementation of `ThreadPool` is its **ability to react to load of the pool by increasing/decreasing its pool size.**

*If you do not have such requirement* (a fixed number of threads work for you) then you might not need an elaborate thread pool. So all you might need a simple class abstracting creating and managing threads.

Comment: With "controlling the number of threads" I actually meant the maximum number - idle threads should be disposed and later re-created when necessary, I will update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [`Partitioner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd422129.aspx) can help you out?

Further informations on how to use it can be found int the [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en).